# Is it more efficient to getManager after each persist?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

```
 for(...) {
     $menuItem = new MenuItem();     
     $menuItem->setName($itemName[$i]);
     $menuItem->setDescription($itemDescription[$i]);
     $menuItem->setprice($itemPrice[$i]);
     $menuItem->setMenuCatagory($menuCatagory);

     $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
     $em->persist($menuCatagory);    
     $em->persist($menuItem);        
 }
 $em->flush();
```

Can I place the $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager(); outside of the for loop or do I have to getManager each time to persist correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gorka LauzirikaI would place it outside the loop, but put the `$em->flush()` inside the loop.

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
for(...) {
    $menuItem = new MenuItem();     
    $menuItem->setName($itemName[$i]);
    $menuItem->setDescription($itemDescription[$i]);
    $menuItem->setprice($itemPrice[$i]);
    $menuItem->setMenuCatagory($menuCatagory);


    $em->persist($menuCatagory);    
    $em->persist($menuItem); 

}
$em->flush();
```

UPDATE

By calling flush() outside the loop, doctrine only needs to perform one query, as was mentioned by Gorka Lauzirika in the comments.

Comment: It would be also correct to put `$em->flush()` outside the loop. Even more, it is recommended to improve performance because you run the query only once, without losing any information

Comment: you are right, I had the wrong idea of how `flush` works.  [This link to the docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#persisting-objects-to-the-database) explains more about the use of `flush`.  I updated my answer